# Get posts only from a selected user

Tags: javascript, meteor

In https:https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope. How do you get posts only from a selected user?

Answer (score 0):

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(options) {
  check(options, {
    sort: Object,
    limit: Number
  });
  return Posts.find({userId:selected_user_id}, options);
});
```

you just have to put it in your post selector, just like you do in the notifications